# Proving that $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Given
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{x} &, 0<x\leq 1 \\
      0 &, x=0 
   \end{cases}
$$
I'm trying to prove that $f$ is not integrable, is my solution is valid ?

So suppose $f$ is integrable, then there should exist a constant function $g=M$ so that $f(x)\leq M,\forall x$ and thus $\int^1_0 f{\rm d}x\leq \int^1_0 M{\rm d}x$ or $\int^1_0f{\rm d}x\leq M.$ However, this is clearly false since we can always find a value of $x$ sufficiently small such that $\frac{1}{x}>M$ for any value of $M.$

Is is correct ?

Comment: You mean "a value of $x$ sufficiently **small**", right?

Comment: @Patricio yep, that is what I meant, I'll edit the post. Thanks

Comment: Note here,  we have an improper integral,  so $f $ need not to be bounded... There is another reason that f is not integradable

Comment: Are you dealing with Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net riemann integrability in the $\delta,\varepsilon$ sense, where the partition of the Riemann sum is $\delta(t)-$fine

Comment: $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ is integrable $\iff$ the following limit exists: $$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_a^1 f(x)dx.$$  This is based on the rules governing the evaluation of an improper integral.  Here, $(a\to 0^+)$ signifies that $a$ is approaching $0$ **from above**.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer a solution from a little more general perspective.
Lets check when does $\int_0^1{x^\alpha}dx$ exists. This happens when $\lim_{t\to0}{\int_t^1{x^\alpha}dx}$ exists. We'll get:

$\lim_{t\to0}\left[\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}\right]_t^1 = \frac{1}{\alpha+1}-\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$ and the second argument diverges if $t$ goes to the denominator, hence we must have $\alpha>-1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int_1^a \frac 1t dt+\int_1^b \frac 1t dt = \int_1^{ab} \frac 1t dt.$$

Big hint:

> $$\int_{\frac 12}^1 \frac 1t dt +\int_{\frac 12}^1 \frac 1t dt =\int_{\frac 14}^1 \frac 1t dt$$